# Grunt-contrib-less fails with Angular-Material @media queries

Tags: css, angularjs, gruntjs, angular-material, grunt-contrib-less

I'm experiencing a strange error with angular-material & grunt-contrib-less.

Every time i'm trying to run a simply `grunt less` task it fails with the following error message

```
>> ParseError: media definitions require block statements after any features in lib/angular-material/angular-material.css on line 654, column 14:
>> 653 
>> 654 @media screen\0 {
>> 655   .flex {
Warning: Error compiling less/libs.less
```

I'm using the latest stable release of angular material (v.1.0.1).

It's required in less like this:

`@import (less) "../lib/angular-material/angular-material.css";`

And this is my task:

```
less: {
            options: {
                compress: true
            },

            libs: {
                files: {
                    'public/src/css/libs.css': 'less/libs.less'
                },
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    outputSourceFiles: true,
                    sourceMapFilename: 'public/src/css/libs.css.map',
                    sourceMapURL: '/src/css/libs.css.map',
                    sourceMapRootpath: '/'
                }
            }

          ....(more tasks here)
}
```

I would love some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `(inline)` instead of `(less)`.

When you use `(less)` the file you import will be treated as a less file, no matter the extension. Therefore, you are trying to process css code as if it was less.

When you use `(inline)` the file contents will just be included as they are, without being processed.

You can read more about this in the [Less docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options).