# less CSS parse error: media definitions require block statements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, media-queries, codekit

I'm using codekit to compile my Bootstrap LESS files and i keep getting this parse error on media queries that i didn't get when it was previously a CSS file.

*"ParseError: media definitions require block statements after any features in /assets/less/homepage.less on line 568, column 2:
567 @media (max-width: @iphone_breakpoint) {
568 }"*

Here is the complete line of code in question:

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media (max-width: @iphone_breakpoint) {
}
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Ho ware you importing this less file? Are you using (less) or (inline)

Comment: i'm using a less file as a master file to import multiple less files to be compiled. Everything goes will until it hits the media queries on the last page which happens to be homepage.less

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438723/grunt-contrib-less-fails-with-angular-material-media-queries

Comment: Importing the file using (inline) compiles but it does not process the variables or mixins in homepage.less

Comment: what's in the @iphone_breakpoint? is it a simple value i.e. 480px or is there a guard?

Comment: Check if it's some non-standar whitespace character (or some other magic stuff) at that line *column 2*. The code itself is valid and [goes fine](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40iphone_breakpoint%3A%20foo%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F*%20Custom%2C%20iPhone%20Retina%20*%2F%20%5Cn%40media%20(max-width%3A%20%40iphone_breakpoint)%20%7B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: solved @seven-phases-max . I re-wrote the media query in less2css to debug, copied it over into the file and it compiled. I'm assuming there was some whitespace issue as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just had this error, found the issue was a simple syntax error. I'll post what worked for me.

**The error**:

```
>> SyntaxError: media definitions require block statements after any
>> features in _assets/less/styles.less on line 144, column 2:
>>
>> 143
>> 144  div {
>> 145          .links {
```

Notice the error shows the line as being around `144-145`, below we'll see

In the code below I've forgot the `.` (period) when using the built in `.hidden()` `mixin` by [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

This outputs the error:

> **SyntaxError: media definitions require block statements after any features in dir/bar/foo.less on line 144, column 2:**

A little misleading as the error is a child within that div on line `149`.

```
div {                // Line 144
    .links {
        .hidden();
    }
    .other-links {
        // Missing `.` for using the mixin
        hidden();    // The real error is here on Line 149
    }
}
```

**Summary:**

Make sure you have no syntax errors in the children where the displayed error noted the error.

1. Check for missing periods before mixins. `hidden() -> .hidden()`
2. Check for all other errors `?`

*Found another syntax error causing this error?*
*let us know, comment below*

Comment: In my case it was a stray ')' that didn't show up as a syntax error in the @media query.

Comment: An omitted colon can have the same effect…

Comment: In my case it was: `display: none; !important`